# akka firstCompletedOf, identify message sender

Tags: scala, akka, future, promise

I'm using Scala 2.10 / Akka 2.1 / Play 2.1, and I have a question about firstCompletedOf. How do I identify the sender of the result in the firstCompletedOf body? Look at the following code:

```
val futureString: Future[String] = myTestActor.ask(Message).mapTo[String]
val timeoutFuture = play.api.libs.concurrent.Promise.timeout("timed_out", 5 seconds)

Async {
  Future.firstCompletedOf(Seq(futureString, timeoutFuture)).map {
    case result: String => {
      println("got message " + result)
    }
  }
}
```

At some point inside `myTestActor` there is a `sender ! "actor_result"`, but the timeout might come first.

Is there a quick, convenient way of identifying the sender of the result? `sender` doesn't work, and I think that a check on the string (if equal to `timed_out`) would be quite dirty.

Comment: I'm not sure this is an answer, so I'll put it in a comment... "Tell, Don't Ask!" Furthermore, when you do tell, tell the receiver where to direct any reply / response / result. This makes for a much more flexible topology of actors that can more easily be reused and recombined in different ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like:

```
val futureString: Future[String] = myTestActor.ask(Message).mapTo[String]
val timeoutFuture: Future[String] = play.api.libs.concurrent.Promise.timeout(throw new TimeoutException(), 5 seconds)

Async {
  Future.firstCompletedOf(Seq(futureString, timeoutFuture)) map {
    case result: String => println("got message " + result)
  } recover {
    case _: TimeoutException => "Timed out?"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Viktor. I am finding it difficult to ramp my way up in Scala / Akka / Play. I hesitate to buy a book as things seem to change really fast and material online is sparse and contradictory. Any help on this?

Comment: Programming in Scala 1Ed is free: http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/, The Akka documentation is around 500 pages, and is free: http://akka.io/docs/, and the Play documentation is free: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/Home . On top of that there's a plethora och conference talks freely available. If you are using the Typesafe Stack you also have these resources: http://typesafe.com/resources/documentation